# and operator on two metrics with one same label - promql

Tags: prometheus, promql

in prometheus, I have two metrics like this:
metricA:

```
metrica{label1="value1",aa="aa",bb="bb"}
```

metricB:

```
metricb{label1="value1",cc="cc",dd="dd"}
```

I want to `and` these two metrics, but each time it shows No data.
How can I `and` these two metrics with just one same label

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer in this [doc](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#one-to-one-vector-matches)
so the solution is:

```
metrica and on(label1) metrib
```